# How to lock aspect ratio of an image in a docx with Apache POI?

Tags: java, image, apache-poi, docx

is there a way to enable the "lock aspect ratio" option for an image in a docx using Apache POI?
I'm adding an image to a run and i'd like to lock its size.
Searched in documentation but nothing found.

To be more clear I am referring to the option available inside word, as showed in the image:
https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/a30a8baa-6775-4931-bca6-199fda6afc6e.png

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on how the picture is applied to the `Word` document. If this was done via [XWPFRun.addPicture](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addPicture-java.io.InputStream-int-java.lang.String-int-int-), it is an inline picture in the text run. Then the run contains a drawing layer which contains a inline element containing the picture. This inline element then may contain non visual graphic frame properties which may have graphic frame locks which set no change aspect true.

The `XML` in `/word/document.xml` looks like:

```
<w:r>
 <w:drawing>
  <wp:inline ...>
   <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="true"/></wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
    <a:graphic>
   ...
```

Then for the `XWPFRun run` containing the picture can be set

```
run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0).getInlineArray(0).addNewCNvGraphicFramePr().addNewGraphicFrameLocks().setNoChangeAspect(true);
```

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class CreateWordPicturesInTextRuns {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  List<String> pictureURLs = new ArrayList<String>();
  pictureURLs.add("https://www.eastcottvets.co.uk/uploads/Animals/gingerkitten.jpg");
  pictureURLs.add("https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/A-kitten-meowing.jpg");
  pictureURLs.add("https://www.animalfriends.co.uk/app/uploads/2014/08/06110347/Kitten-small.jpg");
  pictureURLs.add("https://d27ucmmhxk51xv.cloudfront.net/media/english/illustration/kitten.jpg");

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("The kitten pictures: ");

  URL url;
  BufferedImage image;
  Dimension dim;
  ByteArrayOutputStream bout;
  ByteArrayInputStream bin;
  for (String pictureURL : pictureURLs) {
   try {
       
    url = new URL(pictureURL);
    image = ImageIO.read(url);
    dim = new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    double width = dim.getWidth();
    double height = dim.getHeight();
    double scaling = 1.0;
    if (width > 72*3) scaling = (72*3)/width; //scale width not to be greater than 3 inches

    bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", bout);
    bout.flush();
    bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(bout.toByteArray());
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.addPicture(bin, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "kitten", 
     Units.toEMU(width*scaling), Units.toEMU(height*scaling));

    //lock aspect ratio
    run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0).getInlineArray(0).addNewCNvGraphicFramePr().addNewGraphicFrameLocks().setNoChangeAspect(true);
    
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordPicturesInTextRuns.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```